# How to rebuild an xml key with beautiful soup/python?

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

So, using beautiful soup, I am trying to parse through a large xml file and strip out the first string (before .) from each key name.

Just as an example:

currently print key gives me:

```
<key name="app-suite.multi.port" value="15022"></key>
```

and `print key["name"].split(".")[1:]` gives me:

```
['multicast', 'port']
```

Stripping out app-suite out of the keyname is the desired result, however I'm not sure how to rebuild this key.  Currently the above line just returns a list with the correct elements.

How do I actually turn this into a key or modify the original key by removing 'app-suite'?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you actually want to keep the `.` in `multi.port`, it is better to use `split(., 1)` so that you only split on the first instance of `.`. You can use the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

content = '<key name="app-suite.multi.port" value="15022"></key>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
key = soup.find('key')
key['name'] = key["name"].split(".", 1)[1]
print(key)
```

**Output**

```
<key name="multi.port" value="15022"></key>
```

Comment: will this work if the key name has more than 3 elements?  for example multi.port.value.anothervalue

Comment: @david yes it will - it will simply remove the section of the string up to and including the first `.`